# react child state doesn't update with props from father (and deeper in the branch)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

The problem is following:
I have components: Grandfather, father and child (literally :D).
Grandfather passes his state through props to father (and father sets his state with it).
Then father passes props to child and child also sets state with it.
When i display this.props everything is fine, but when i display
state then i see that nothing has changed in father and child.
I heard there is something like componentWillReceiveProps() but it is already deprecated.

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/doesitworkornot-rrcgt?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

And codes:

Grandfather.js

```
import React from "react";
import Father from "./Father";

class GrandFather extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      clickedCounter: 1
    };
  }

  onClick = e => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      clickedCounter: prevState.clickedCounter + 1
    }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.onClick}>Press me</button> <br />
        Here is Grandfather -> state value={this.state.clickedCounter}
        <Father clickedCounter={this.state.clickedCounter} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default GrandFather;
```

Father.js

```
import React from "react";
import Child from "./Child";

class Father extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      clickedCounter: this.props.clickedCounter
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Here is Father -> props value={this.props.clickedCounter} <br />
        Here is Father -> state value={this.state.clickedCounter}
        <Child clickedCounter={this.props.clickedCounter} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Father;
```

Child.js

```
import React from "react";

class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      clickedCounter: this.props.clickedCounter
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Here is Child -> props value={this.props.clickedCounter} <br />
        Here is Child -> state value={this.state.clickedCounter}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Child;
```

I also heard there is something like cloning children... I'd like to avoid it if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you initialise state from props, react will not refresh state but it do refresh props. You can use below code to make it work instead of componentWillReceiveProps.

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps) {    
    return {
      clickedCounter: nextProps.clickedCounter,
    }
}
```